# How can I call mouseover event handler programmatically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In my html, I have an html element with a mouseover event handler.
Can you please tell me if it is possible for me to invoke that event handler programmically in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, it is. (what, you didn't ask HOW do to that :D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. Here's a cross browser function to fire an event:

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
    if (el.fireEvent) {
      el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
    } else {
      var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
      evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
      el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}
// => exmaples
// => eventFire(myDiv,'mouseover');
// => eventFire(myButton,'click');
```

Comment: Is usually recommended to check the standard features first (`document.createEvent` in this example) and later the proprietary ones...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fireEvent method available for IE. I am not sure if this will work for FF or other browsers.  you can simply fire the event by

```
buttonObject.fireEvent('onclick');
```

For more details have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(VS.85).aspx).