# Analyzing DOM Event via Firebug :hover

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, firebug

I have an issue I'm trying to debug, and normally I would use Firebug's awesome :hover status toggle (under the "style" dropdown tab on the right).  However, In this case I need to inspect the DOM an element Y that is being dynaimcally generated by javascript when element X is hovered.  Toggling Firebug's ":hover" option under the style tab is not locking the DOM and I can't get element Y to be visible for inspection.  Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the onmouseover event handler manually from the Firebug console. (Most javascript frameworks provide shortcuts for this, e.g. if you use jQuery for hover handling, you can just say `$('#some-element').trigger('mouseover')` (or possibly `mouseenter`, though probably both work).)

Comment: thanks! When you say "Call the onmouseover event handler manually from the Firebug console..." I'm afraid that I'm not sure what you mean by this.  Where in the Firebug console can I do this?

Comment: @Brian: You can execute any javascript from the Firbug console (choose the Console tab, you might have to enable it; then there will be either a box on the right side or a bar on the bottom, depending on your setup, where you can type). See [the docs](http://getfirebug.com/commandline). How exactly you run the handler depends on what script or framework you use, see e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979370/how-can-i-call-mouseover-event-handler-programmically-in-javascript).